# else block not executing after successful execution of if/elif blocks

Tags: python

Here is the question I have been asked to answer (in Python):

> You live in a big apartment block, and sorting mail and parcels is quite a complex task. Write a program that reads in a file with all the deliveries, asks for the user's name and prints out a summary of all the mail.
>
> Your program should read in a file named mail.txt that looks like this:
>
> ```
> Jane Fairfax,Letter
> Frank Churchill,Letter
> Emma Woodhouse,Letter
> Frank Churchill,Letter
> Harriet Smith,Package
> Emma Woodhouse,Letter
> Philip Elton,Package
> Emma Woodhouse,Package
> ```
>
> Your program should work like this:
>
> ```
> Name: Emma Woodhouse
> 2 Letters
> 1 Package
> ```
>
> Here is another example:
>
> ```
> Name: Jane Fairfax
> 1 Letter
> No Packages
> ```
>
> If the person doesn't have any mail, your program should work like this:
>
> ```
> Name: Elizabeth Bennet
> No mail
> ```

Here is my solution so far:

```
import csv

dictionary = {}

name = input('Name: ')

with open('mail.txt', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for line in reader:
    key, value = line[0], line[1]
    if key in dictionary:
      dictionary[key].append(value)
    else:
      dictionary[key] = [value]
    
for person, items in dictionary.items():
  lettercount = 0
  packagecount = 0
  if person == name:
    for item in items:
      if item == 'Letter':
        lettercount += 1
      else:
        packagecount += 1

    l = ''
    p = ''
    if lettercount == 0:
      l = 'No Letters'
    elif packagecount == 0:
      p = 'No Packages'
    elif lettercount == 1:   
      l = '1 Letter'
    elif packagecount == 1:
      p = '1 Package'
    elif packagecount == 0 and lettercount == 0:
      print('No mail')
    else:
      l = f'{lettercount} Letters'
      p = f'{packagecount} Packages'
      print('e')
      
    print(l)
    print(p)
```

This is the output of my code, given the name Emma Woodhouse. No matter the name, if they have no or 1 package/letter it works, but as soon as there is more than 1 it doesn't work.

```
Name: Emma Woodhouse

1 Package
```

I have determined the issue must be here as I cannot see anything wrong with the previous variables.

```
    if lettercount == 0:
      l = 'No Letters'
    elif packagecount == 0:
      p = 'No Packages'
    elif lettercount == 1:   
      l = '1 Letter'
    elif packagecount == 1:
      p = '1 Package'
    elif packagecount == 0 and lettercount == 0:
      print('No mail')
    else:
      l = f'{lettercount} Letters'
      p = f'{packagecount} Packages'
      print('e')
```

For some reason, the else statement will not trigger, as I tested by asking it to print e. I have tried basically everything up to this point. I have asked ChatGPT in about every way possible (to no avail), tried changing `l` and `p` only under the else statement, tried using elif statements such as

```
elif lettercount > 1: 
  l = f'{lettercount} Letters'
```

and seeing if that gets executed (it doesnt), I even tried using different data types.

Comment: Looks like you need to learn [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). BTW, there's no need to loop over `dictionary` when you could just do `items = dictionary[name]`

Comment: Er, `items = dictionary.get(name, [])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
if lettercount == 0:
  l = 'No Letters'
elif packagecount == 0:
  p = 'No Packages'
elif lettercount == 1:
  l = '1 Letter'
elif packagecount == 1:
  p = '1 Package'
elif packagecount == 0 and lettercount == 0:
  print('No mail')
else:
  l = f'{lettercount} Letters'
  p = f'{packagecount} Packages'
```

You're using a single `if/elif/else` structure, so it will only execute **one** of the code blocks.

In the sample data, Emma Woodhouse does have one package, so the `elif packagecount == 1` block is executed.  The final `else` block is **not** executed.

Rearrange your code to handle letters and packages separately:

```
if lettercount == 0:
    ...
elif lettercount  == 1:
    ...
else:
    ...

if packagecount == 0:
    ...
elif packagecount == 1:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I searched up if any part of an if statement is executed will it go end but it didn't help. It makes sense but I just couldn't see that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out is that you've got an unnecessary loop in your code: you have a dictionary keyed by name; there's no need to loop through all the names looking for a match. You can just ask for `dictionary[name]`.

The logic you're using to determine the output seems a little convoluted.

You could tackle both problems with something like this:

```py
import csv


def formatcount(kind, count):
    if not count:
        return f"No {kind}s"
    else:
        return f'{count} {kind}{"s" if count > 1 else ""}'


def read_mail_data(path):
    maildict = {}
    with open(path, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for line in reader:
            name, kind = line[0], line[1]
            if name not in maildict:
                maildict[name] = {"Letter": 0, "Package": 0}

            maildict[name][kind] += 1
    return maildict


dictionary = read_mail_data("mail.txt")
name = input("Name: ")
lettercount = packagecount = 0
items = dictionary.get(name)

if not items or not (items["Letter"] or items["Package"]):
    print("No mail")
else:
    print(formatcount("letter", items["Letter"]))
    print(formatcount("package", items["Package"]))
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I am not quite there with coming up with more advanced/optimised solution using functions, but its great to see one where its used.
{"s" if count > 1 else ""} Why is there an else used here? Surely {"s" if count > 1"} works the same? Also, maildict[name][kind] += 1 how does this work, where you apply two things at once, like [name][kind] to a dictionary. Is that like a key, value pair being added?

Comment: @Shark f-strings cannot have empty expressions. So, when `if` is used `else` is mandatory (otherwise the expression would be empty if the condition is not met). Try both and see what happens :)